# create an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a function in jQuery

```
  jQuery(function () {
      jQuery(".one").showcase({
          animation: { type: "fade" },
          titleBar: { autoHide: false },
          navigator: { autoHide: true }
      });
      prettyPrint();
      jQuery(".two").showcase({
          animation: { type: "fade" },
          titleBar: { autoHide: false },
          navigator: { autoHide: true }
      });
      prettyPrint();
      jQuery(".three").showcase({
          animation: { type: "fade" },
          titleBar: { autoHide: false },
          navigator: { autoHide: true }
      });
      prettyPrint();
  });
```

now note the code above. i repeat the showcase function three times. I want create the function once by array. how can it possible. I saw the jQuery array example, but cant understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
  jQuery(function () {
      var arObj = ['.one','.two','.three'];

      for(var i = 0; i< arObj.length ; i++){
          jQuery(arObj[i]).showcase({
              animation: { type: "fade" },
              titleBar: { autoHide: false },
              navigator: { autoHide: true }
          });
          prettyPrint();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way wouldn't be to use an array, but to alter the jQuery selector to target all 3 at once;

```
  jQuery(".one,.two,.three").showcase({
      animation: { type: "fade" },
      titleBar: { autoHide: false },
      navigator: { autoHide: true }
  });
  prettyPrint();
```

... which uses the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), although you might want to add *another* class to those elements `showcase`(?) and call it like;

```
  jQuery(".showcase").showcase({
      animation: { type: "fade" },
      titleBar: { autoHide: false },
      navigator: { autoHide: true }
  });
  prettyPrint();
```

... instead.

Comment: if there is a number of class,then it is not better to write like that

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array-based solution, you can do something like:

```
jQuery.each([".one", ".two", ".three"], function(index, value) {
    jQuery(value).showcase({
        animation: { type: "fade" },
        titleBar: { autoHide: false },
        navigator: { autoHide: true }
    });
    prettyPrint();
});
```

...or:

```
function fadeAll(arr) {
    jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        jQuery(value).showcase({
            animation: { type: "fade" },
            titleBar: { autoHide: false },
            navigator: { autoHide: true }
        });
        prettyPrint();
    });
}
```

Otherwise just go with Matt's answer.